# Elixir - Manipulating a 2 dimensional list

Tags: arraylist, types, elixir

Hope everybody is having a beautiful 2019 even though we're just a day in.

I am currently working on a small Phoenix app where I'm manipulating PDF files (in the context of this question I'm splitting them) and then uploading them to S3. Later on I have to delete the temporary files created by pdftk ( a pdf tool ) I use to split them up and also show the s3 links in the response body since this is an API request.

The way I have structured this is as following:

Inside my `Split` module where the core business logic is:

```
filenames = []
 s3_links = []
 Enum.map(pages, fn(item) ->
        split_filename = item
          |> split(filename)
        link = split_filename
          |> FileHelper.result_file_bytes()
          |> ManageS3.upload()
          |> FileHelper.save_file(work_group_id, pass)

        [filenames ++ split_filename, s3_links ++ link]
      end)
      |> transform()
    {filenames, s3_links}
```

The important things are split_filename and link 
This is what I'm getting when I call an IO.inspect in the transform() method:

```
[
  ["87cdcd73-5b27-4757-a472-78aaf6cc6864.pdf",
   "Some_S3_LINK00"],

  ["0ab460ca-5019-4864-b0ff-343966c7d72a.pdf",
   "Some_S3_LINK01"]
]
```

The structuring is `[[filename, s3_link], [filename, s3_link]]` whereas the desired outcome would be that of `[ [list of all filenames], [list of s3 links]`.

If anybody can lend a hand I would be super grateful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sidenotes:*

1. Assigning `filenames = []; s3_links = []` in the very beginning makes zero sense. `Enum.map` already *maps* the input. What you need is probably [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#reduce/3).
2. Don’t use the pipe `|>` operator when the pipe consists of the only call, it is considered an anti-pattern by Elixir core team.
3. Always start pipes with a term.

---

*Solution:*

Reduce the input into the result using [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#reduce/3) directly to what you need.

```rb
pages
|> Enum.reduce([[], []], fn item, [files, links] ->
  split_filename = split(item, filename)
  link =
    split_filename
    |> FileHelper.result_file_bytes()
    |> ManageS3.upload()
    |> FileHelper.save_file(work_group_id, pass)

  [[split_filename | files], [link | links]]
end)
|> Enum.map(&Enum.reverse/1)
|> IO.inspect(label: "Before transform")
|> transform()
```

You did not provide the input to test it, but I believe it should work.

Comment: Thank you for the descriptive answer, this works too. I just had to add a call to Enum.reverse() as the inputs need to be in the order I receive them and here we're appending them to the `head` of the list ` [[split_filename | files], [link | links]]`. You are absolutely right on `1.` I don't need them. Can you elaborate on point `2.` what do you mean by _when the pipe consists only of the call_? Thanks and Cheers :)

Comment: When there is only one pipe operator in the chain, it is not a pipe. Do `Mod.fun(arg)` not `arg |> Mod.fun()`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of working on lists of lists, you may want to consider using tuples with lists. Something like the following should work for you.

```
List.foldl(pages, {[], []}, fn(item, {filenames, links}) ->
  filename = split(item, filename)

  link =
    file_name
    |> FileHelper.result_file_bytes()
    |> ManagerS3.upload()
    |> FileHelper.save_file(work_group_id, pass)

  {[filename | filenames], [link | links]}
end)
```

This will return a value that looks like

```
{
  ["87cdcd73-5b27-4757-a472-78aaf6cc6864.pdf",
   "0ab460ca-5019-4864-b0ff-343966c7d72a.pdf"],

  ["Some_S3_LINK00",
   "Some_S3_LINK01"]
}
```

Though, depending on how you are using these values, maybe a list of tuples would be more appropriate. Something like

```
Enum.map(pages, fn(item) ->
  filename = split(item, filename)

  link =
    filename
    |> FileHelper.result_file_bytes()
    |> ManageS3.upload()
    |> FileHelper.save_file(work_group_id, pass)

  {filename, link}
end)
```

would return

```
[
  {"87cdcd73-5b27-4757-a472-78aaf6cc6864.pdf", "Some_S3_LINK00"},
  {"0ab460ca-5019-4864-b0ff-343966c7d72a.pdf", "Some_S3_LINK01"}
]
```

Comment: The idea of using List.foldl looks great. My main problem was trying to figure out a way of using an Enum function in some way. For example Enum.map(), Enum.each(). Still green at not applying OOP ideas to Elixir. 
As for the tuple idea: Is there an advantage to making a list of tuples?  The reason why I needed the filenames and s3 links separate is so that I can return the s3 links as an array in the response body and later use the filenames for manually cleaning out the ./tmp/ directory where I invoke the pdftk operations.

Comment: @StiliyanHristov Tuples would just make it easier to access each item in the array. The parent would still be an  array though.

Comment: Sounds good. But I need them in an array form because I have different functions() which remove all files after everything is done and they expect a list. I'll keep that in mind in the future though. Thank you : )